# problemas con Action_send : ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio

hola estoy ejecuntando action_send pero se me detiene la aplicacion estoy utlizando android 7 y con otras versiones funciona pero con esta se detiene.

```
String email = "kevinavira@hotmail.com";

                    Intent intentMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"+email));

                    intentMail.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
                    intentMail.setType("plain/text");
                    intentMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "mails title");
                    intentMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi there, i love Myform app..");
                    intentMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"kevin@hotmail.com","Antonio@gmail.com"});
    startActivity(intentMail);
```

Comment: Que dispositivo estas utilizando? Para ese código funcionar gmail debe de estar instalado.

Comment: si claro ya pobre solo CON ACTION_SENDTO y me funciona pero con este  se detiene

Comment: Kevin, en desarrollo Android es importante el uso del LogCat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguramente tienes una excepción del tipo `ActivityNotFoundException` , te sugiero agregar manejo de excepciones cuando inicies la Activity:

```
try {
    startActivity(intentMail);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    //Error no existe Activity.
}
```

Es importante en este caso que tengas instalada la aplicación de Gmail ya que estas especificando el paquete: `"com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail"`

Te sugiero no especificar el paquete de Gmail para que pueda enviarse el email con cualquier cliente:

```
    String email = "kevinavira@hotmail.com";
    Intent intentMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"+email));
  //intentMail.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
    intentMail.setType("plain/text");
    intentMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "mails title");
    intentMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi there, i love Myform app..");
    intentMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"kevin@hotmail.com","Antonio@gmail.com"});
        try {
            startActivity(intentMail);
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            //Error no existe Activity.
        }
```

Comment: si me funciono comentando el set.classsName pero lo que no entiendo si tengo gmail porque que se detiene la aplicacion? @Jorgesys ♦

Comment: Porque el paquete que especificas no existe en tu dispositivo, y lo que realiza ahora el intent es abrir los clientes instalados que puedan realizar el envio de un email.